# Why laptop boots usb but incorrect resolution after installing to hard drive?

Tags: 12.04, display

My situation: Dell Inspiron 1100 laptop 1GB, 20GB HD. (1024 X 748). Boots Ubuntu 12.04 from USB to Desktop fine. After installing to HD though it seems like it's in 640 X 480 - double screen, black on right side, flickering after booting from HD. I am new to linux and am looking for direction to resolve this. I am cross-eyed from reading and feel that I'm getting close but....I've smacked the thing that didn't help!

I found somewhat dated thread that suggested interupting the grub by holding left shift and editing the line that ends in "quiet splash" but no success with the suggested options.

Any takers? Meanwhile I'll keep trudging across the tundra, mile after mile...

Good day and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can always press the CTRL+ALT+x, where:

- x from 1 to 6 are simple terminals
- x = 7 is X window system

So you can start cracking it from the command line.

Try starting with the following logs and configs:

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/Xorg.0.log

/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

If everything works well from the USB, but not from the HDD, you can also compare the GRUB boot options:

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

for given "menuentry" (as you already mentioned)

You can also change the /etc/default/grub to make the changes permanent.

Please see this for example: http://www.intdblog.com/2009/09/grub-2-graphical-boot-tips-to-set.html

Comment: by 1 to 6, you mean `f1` to `f6`. that's not exactly clear in the answer.

Comment: No response to CTRL+ALT+x(1-7) but I can get to term emu w/CTRL+ALT+T. I am still working on it though. Seems to be inconsistent. Now boots to black screen with USB. Not giving up!

Comment: I got the F-key note and that does respond, however reports " Can't open display" for the xrandr command. xrandr works in the desktop terminal. --addmode fails: Badmatch (invalid parameter attributes)

Comment: Update: I have connected a Dell 19" ext monitor and then restarted. The laptop's display now is at 1024 X 768 and stable. Xrandr reports 3 modes 640x480, 800x600 and the current 1024x768. I am still pursuing explanation/resolution as I would like to have laptop boot w/o ext mon. (I use ext mon on another PC). Thanks for your suggestions as I feel I learned alot. Btw, no display on ext mon, but I suppose that is another subject.

Comment: I also faced a problem with my no so old nVidia graphics card that the nVidia PROPRIETARY driver was detecting wrong available resolutions. That happened when I tried newer version (304.60 at that time) and was related to my Lenovo WSXGA display.

AFAIK, Nouveau driver was better in this case.

Comment: Thanks again for your help - I'm going to close this question and ask again in a different way. I will copy and paste the info from this one. This is where things are: With no external monitor connected my laptop boots to the 12.04 Desktop in 600X480 mode and xrandr only reports that mode for LVSD1

Comment: With the ext monitor conn, the laptop boots to the desktop in 1024x768 mode and everything is fine (?) No display on ext. mon. I thought I might find something in a config file but no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark but it seems to me that it would be using drivers already installed when running from cd but after install video card drivers need to be updated before it can run correctly?